# I have a regular flex-cable, which I want to connect to a computer via USB

Tags: usb, camera

Is it possible to connect a flex-cable to a USB. Specifically I want to connect the Raspberry Pi's camera to a computer.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is No, it cannot be done.

The Raspberry Pi camera uses a dedicated camera interface with 10 signal wires. USB has just 2 (along with 2 more for power). What you need is to convert the 10 wires from the camera into USB, and the best thing to do that is the Raspberry Pi itself. If you google "raspberry pi usb camera" you should find that many people have implemented this before. Another way to do it is to use the Raspberry Pi's ethernet connection, so you make the Pi into an IP camera. Again, this has been done before.

Comment: and if use the connector part too, they are cheap but i don t really understand what they do. Anyways i am not looking for an easy answer, if it is possible in a difficult way i would be happy to learn about it.

Comment: @FerdinandWittmann do you mean connect the Pi's camera directly to a PC? The PC does not have a suitable interface. You need some thing to convert from CSI (Camera Serial Interface) to USB or Ethernet - the Pi is the obvious choice.

Comment: OK i didn t really ask what i was looking for. I guess your answer alreay answerd my next question but anyways: i have the pis camera and an android phone. I now want to connect it to the phone via its usb port. So in the end i would have something like a camera phone case. Since the phone has all the hardware needed and i can use the same drivers for the phone which i would use for the pi. The only hard part is to get the data from the camera to the phones kernel, since the phone has only a micro usb port. Could you think of any solution to this without an extra controller.

Comment: @FerdinandWittmann same problem. You need to get a USB camera.